# Does React.js require server side?

Tags: reactjs

All React.js introductions seem to suggest that React uses a server to create virtual DOMs and sends diff operations over to client, but I just tried out the [flux-todomvc](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc/) which it didn't need a server at all. What's going on? Is the "server side" work done inside web worker thread?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

React.js does not use a web server to create virtual DOMs. It builds the virtual DOM and does its diff operations on the client's browser.

- People mostly use React.js to implement front-end Views (MVC View) of their web applications.
- But you can use Node.js to render them on the server side if you like (for seo purposes etc.)
- http://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: Well someone has to serve react files so that the front end view loads the page. I don't get it, where do we get the react webpage FROM?